# SUM all values, whose adjacent cell value is not present in other columns

Tags: excel, sum, formulas

[Discounts Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R40lV.jpg)

I have a table with the discount [D2:D11] for different products. The discount is later used in columns G, I, K. I am trying to figure out what formula should I use, in order to sum the amount of each discount, whose ID [C2:C11] is not present in columns F, H or J. For example discounts DGYUR, DPOIU, DXCER, DSZAQ and DICTP are not present in columns F, H or J, hence their discount amount should be calculated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Sumif with a "<>" comes to mind as a possible solution.

Comment: I've tried sumifs but the formula doesn't seem to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Excel expert by any stretch and I'm sure there are ways to tighten this up. As I was playing around with this in Excel Online I can't even use array formulas. This should get you started at least.

If you place this formula in `E2` and copy it down you'll see which values need to be counted.

```
=IF(AND(
    ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, F$2:F$11, 1, FALSE)),
    ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, H$2:H$11, 1, FALSE)),
    ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, J$2:J$11, 1, FALSE))), B2, 0)
```

You should be able to use a sum on that column (or a sum with an array formula) to get the final total.